# settimeout = setinterval with delay?

Tags: javascript, html

Quick question regarding settimeout, does it execute periodically like setinterval?

Say I have a line that goes like `setTimeout("functionx();" , 1000)` , 
is functionx() executed only once (after 1 second)? or does it go like this:

1. 1 sec delay
2. run functionx()
3. execute functionx every 1 second after that?

thanks

Comment: Your internet research couldn't give you a decent answer? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout | You could also just try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setTimeout` is a one-off, the function you give it is called only once.

(Off-topic: Note that you almost never want to give either `setTimeout` or `setInterval`  a string containing code; instead, give it an actual function reference.)

So this will call the function `foo` once, after half a second *or so* (these things are not precise):

```
function foo() {
    display("Hi there");
}
setTimeout(foo, 500);
```

...whereas this will keep calling it every half second *or so* until you stop it:

```
var timer = setInterval(foo, 500);
// Somewhere else, stop it:
clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 1):

With [**`setTimeout()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), the function will be executed **only once**, after the specified delay.

That single execution is precisely the difference with [**`setInterval()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval), which calls the function repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) will execute the given function after the given milliseconds. [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) will execute the given function every given milliseconds. If you want setTimeout to act like setInterval, you'll have to make the function you specified recursive.

Comment: [Please don't link to W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/) as JavaScript reference, and *especially* not its pages on `setInterval` and `setTimeout`